# Is it possible to turn the access_logs block on and off via the environment_name variable?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, terraform

I'm looking at using the [new conditionals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals) in **Terraform v0.11** to basically turn a config block on or off depending on the evnironment.

Here's the block that I'd like to make into a conditional, if, for example I have a variable to turn on for production.

```
access_logs {
    bucket = "my-bucket"
    prefix = "${var.environment_name}-alb"
}
```

I think I have the logic for checking the environment conditional, but I don't know how to stick the above configuration into the logic.

```
"${var.environment_name == "production" ? 1 : 0 }"
```

Is it possible to turn the `access_logs` block on and off via the `environment_name` variable?  If this is not possible, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the current terraform, the `if` statement is only a value and can not be used for the block.

There is a workaround in this case. You can set the `enabled` attribute of the `access_log` block to `false`. Note that this is not a general solution but can only be used with the `access_log` block.

```
access_logs {
    bucket  = "my-bucket"
    prefix  = "${var.environment_name}-alb"
    enabled = "${var.environment_name == "production" ? true : false }"
}
```

See also:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elb.html#access_logs
- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/alb.html#access_logs
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/11120

Comment: Nice, it looks like I lucked out in my use case.

Comment: There are some resources where you can have a similar effect by setting count to a value of 0 or 1.

Answer (score 42):

One way to achieve this with TF 0.12 onwards is to use [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html):

```
dynamic "access_logs" {
  for_each = var.environment_name == "production" ? [var.environment_name] : []
  content {
    bucket  = "my-bucket"
    prefix  = "${var.environment_name}-alb"
  }
}
```

This will create one or zero access_logs blocks depending on the value of var.environment_name.

Comment: I had to wrap the properties in a `content` block, otherwise this worked perfectly!

`content {
    bucket  = "my-bucket"
    prefix  = "${var.environment_name}-alb"
  }`

Answer (score 21):

Expanding on Juho Rutila's answer as it's too much to fit in a comment.

This is possible using dynamic blocks from v0.12, but I found the properties had to be included in a nested `content` block. The `for_each` statement is also a bit tricky, so I found it sensible to extract that into a local to make the important stuff more readable:

```
locals {
  isProd = var.environment_name == "production" ? [1] : []

  // Not necessary, but just illustrating that the reverse is possible
  isNotProd = var.environment_name == "production" ? [] : [1]
}

dynamic "access_logs" {
  for_each = local.isProd
  content {
    bucket  = "my-bucket"
    prefix  = "${var.environment_name}-alb"
  }
}
```

You can read more about dynamic blocks here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks

Comment: Couldn't I also use the count attribute on, let's say, aws resources in a similar way to express if they shall be present in an environment (yielding count eq 1) or not (yielding count eq 0)?

Comment: Absolutely, that is the standard way of doing that. It's less confusing than this question about dynamic config blocks because it's just a plain `count = 0 or 1` statement, rather than `for_each` where the array length determines what gets built (empty, or length 1)

Comment: If you want to expand an answer you can also just hit the 'edit' button.

Answer (score 1):

Conditionals in terraform are currently only to be used to determine a value, not to be used as an `if` statement wrapping a block.

> And you can also use conditionals to determine a value based on some logic.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#conditionals

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Juho Rutila’s answer too; I like to use the `range` function for this use case:

```
dynamic "access_logs" {
  for_each = range(var.environment_name == "production" ? 1 : 0)

  contents {
    bucket  = "my-bucket"
    prefix  = "${var.environment_name}-alb"
  }
}
```

`range(n)` produces a *n*-element list.