# How to use if else-if else condition in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am trying to change the stack name based on the environment. I tried the following:

```
stack_name = "intl-${var.intl_region}-${var.intl_ctry}-${var.intl_env}-jk-${var.vanity_env == "-np" || var.vanity_env == "-dr"} ? "mstr" : "master"}"
```

but getting the following error:

> Error: Error parsing
>   /build_workspace/workspace/GCM/PIPE_JENKINS/main.tf: At 33:25: nested
>   object expected: LBRACE got: ASSIGN

Can some please help me how can I change the stack name based on the environment?

It should be like:

```
if a == a || b ? "c ": "d"
```

so:

```
a==b==c else d
```

Comment: Please check the link it has the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461753/terraform-conditional-block-based-on-environment

Comment: The only issue looks like an extra ending curly brace. `${var.vanity_env == "-np" || var.vanity_env == "-dr"} ? "mstr" : "master"}"` should be `${var.vanity_env == "-np" || var.vanity_env == "-dr" ? "mstr" : "master"}"`

Answer (score 2):

You've got the syntax for the ternary slightly wrong there:

```
stack_name = intl-${var.intl_region}-${var.intl_ctry}-${var.intl_env}-jk-${var.vanity_env == "-np" || var.vanity_env == "-dr" ? "mstr" : "master"}
```

Note that the whole ternary statement sits inside the `${}` construct.

As a complete example:

```
variable "intl_region" {
  default = "foo"
}

variable "intl_ctry" {
  default = "bar"
}

variable "intl_env" {
  default = "baz"
}

variable "vanity_env" {}

output "foo" {
  value = "intl-${var.intl_region}-${var.intl_ctry}-${var.intl_env}-jk-${var.vanity_env == "-np" || var.vanity_env == "-dr" ? "mstr" : "master"}"
}
```

And running it:

```
$ TF_VAR_vanity_env=-np terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

foo = intl-foo-bar-baz-jk-mstr
$ TF_VAR_vanity_env=-dr terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

foo = intl-foo-bar-baz-jk-mstr
$ TF_VAR_vanity_env=quux terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

foo = intl-foo-bar-baz-jk-master
```